# Good training/test results, but very poor performance in inference as the stream data is coming

Tags: inference, accuracy, generalization, audio, mfcc

I am interested in the audio classification problem. After labeling the audio recordings I have in Praat software environment, I extract the MFCC features from each labeled frame and create an SVM classifier model from random 80%-20% separated data set. The results are quite good on the 20% separated test data, the test accuracy is around 90%, while the 5-fold cross-validation accuracy on the training data is around 90%, and the model hyperparameters were selected by optimizing the them with cross validation accuracy on training data. So far everything is perfect.

The problem starts with records that the model has never seen before. The interval results over the whole recording, which I split into frames & windows, are very bad.  I also use a post-processing algorithm that combines the probability values of consequtive frames, but the model returns high classification results on very irrelevant points.

If the performance on single label test results is so high (both training and test), why are the inference (data is coming as stream) results so irrelevant? The records I use for inference are very similar in content to the records I use in training/test. Am I having this problem because MFCC does not carry temporal information in real time processing? Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Several possibilities come to mind to explain this, but whether they are applicable depends on the details.  Could you clarify what you mean by a "labeled label," tell us about the dataset you have used, and explain how you split it into test and training portions?

Comment: What are the similarities and differences of your streamed data compared to train/test datasets?

Comment: It seems your input is speech, which means that it is spoken by someone and recorded on a particular recording device and recording locations. Have you ensured that your validation/test splits contain unseen speakers/recorders/locations?

Comment: Is this binary or multi-class classification? What is the class balance like?

Comment: @whuber "labelled label" is wrong of course I fixed it sorry. What I mean is manually labelled frames that I want to detect by classification algorithm.

Comment: @JonNordby Similarity: The collected records are coming from the same source(I mean hardware). I have take X audio records, where X is number. Then I extracted features from the manually labelled frames and I obtained the feature vectors for each class(where I have 2 frames; binary classification problem). After getting each feature vectors, randomly selected 80% of them is for training, 20% of for testing.
Differences: In contrast to looking only the frames, streamed data behaves as coming from real time. So, I am looking for the whole records when extracting features by overlapping frames

Comment: @JonNordby    Yes, the model is balanced in terms of the number of instances.

Comment: If an audio recording is a sequence of frames, then those frames are likely to be strongly correlated.  This makes it easy to predict randomly removed frames (because all the frames in the holdout subset are very much like the frames in the training subset) but does little for predicting frames that are not correlated.

Comment: @whuber You are right, but I randomly construct the extracted features and split randomly %80-20 training and test. So, train set does not take the whole instances from the same audio recording.

Comment: Only a small amount of contamination will lead to severe data leakage. You need to fix your splits in order to have metrics that can hope to estimate generalized performance